# Virtualbox on Ubuntu headless mode

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, headless

I have some VMs that I get to by SSHing into my workstation and starting the VMs in headless mode and then connecting to them via RDP (they are windows VMs and I'm using the windows RDP access, not the Virtualbox RDF). When I go into my office though, I can't access the VMs using the native VirtualBox interface although I can see that they are running. Is there any way to take a headless VM to a non-headless (headed ?!?) without stopping the VM and then restarting it via the UI?

I could just connect via RDP locally I know, but it just isn't like the native VirtualBox UI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be to install [phpVirtualBox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/) on your workstation (it will require installing Apache and PHP) and then use that to manage the VMs via a web browser in all cases - in other words, stop using SSH altogether.

There would be security concerns to consider, granted, but this could be a possible solution for you.